# Google Streetview Marker Icon Size reduces automatically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I am using the Google Maps API v3 to show a Google (StreetviewPanorama) and place markers in it.

It's like typical Google Streetview, but with inside buildings not the street.

So I managed to place a marker in it with the following code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: streetview.getPosition(), // Test LatLng Position Value
    icon: {
        url: 'images/alert-icon.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size( hotspot.content.width, hotspot.content.height ),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size( hotspot.content.width, hotspot.content.height )
    },
    title: 'Alert',
    draggable: true,
    clickable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: false
});
marker.setMap( streetview );
```

Following problems:

1. At the start of the Streetview, I have to "Move" to another point to display the marker. Can I make it display right at the start of the StreetviewPanorama and not after I "move" to another Point?
2. To test the markers, I made them draggable. If I drag them over the middle of the Panorama-Height, the Marker-Icon starts to reducing his size.

Let me try to specify "over the middle of the Panorama-Height":

When you take a Panorama Picture, you know where your Head is, this is like the middle of your Eye-Sighs. If you look upper you can see over the head of other people.. if you look much more upper, you can see the stars..

Ok, at this point, we you look "Over the head of other people" the icon starts to reduce his Size.

This behaviour should stop! I tryed to analyse it with the following code:

```
var mouse_up = google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "mouseup", function( e ){
    console.log( marker.getPosition(), marker.getIcon() );
});
```

The size and the scalableSize of the Icon stays the same (hotspot.content.width and height = 50px).

So I don't understand why the icon gets smaller. If I drag the icon to high over the "Head of other people" and drop the icon, it disappears because it is to small.

An image with the problem:

[image]

You can see 3 markers, everyone with a Size of 50px,50px. The higher I drag or position them, the smaller they get, until disappearing.

In example, I want to place one of them to the light. So clicking on the icon near the light will open a Highlightbox saying "This is a light". But I can't do this, when the Icon gets to small or disappear.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Interesting question. Would it be possible to have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the issue is that Google assumes that your markers are placed "at street-level" as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays) says. Dragging a marker to the upper part of the panorama is like dragging it away.

I don't know if there is a way to change this behavior.

Check the following fiddle:

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/7Gmg9/)</kbd>

Switch to streetview, drag the marker to the upper part of the panorama, then switch off the streetview and check where your marker is on the map. Far away.

I have tried playing with the POV. I thought maybe the pitch would change something but it does not seem to be the case.

```
panorama.setPov({
    heading: 200,
    zoom: 1,
    pitch: 30
});
```

Comment: Hello MrUpsidown, thanks for your answer. Seems like its the "at street-level". Maybe markers are not the right solution for this problem. I try to manually add a image and use a function to replace them at the right place, everytime the Point-of-View is changed. Currently I couldn't find the right formula, but I give my best. Thanks for taking time!

Comment: Yes you are right. I don't think markers were meant to be used that way. Please post your solution here if you find a workaround. That could be useful to others.

Comment: Now I try to add a div with a background image and position it with top and left. This look to be a possible way, but I can't figure out the formula. I can get the radian of the degree value, but I don't know what I should do with this value. Do you or someone else know any tipps and tricks to help me in this situation?

Comment: Post what you have in a jsfiddle or at least update your question with some code. That will help.